# Unknown DataSource transport type 'json'. Error on expanding/collapsing Kendo PanelBar

Tags: kendo-panelbar, asp.net-core-8, kendo-asp.net-core

I have recently encountered an unusual problem in my dotnet core project,that is, problem in expanding and collapsing columns. Yes that sounds pretty basic, and yes there are pretty much solutions available out there. But, it does not seems to be working in dotnet core 8.0 and on a specific scenario

I basically created a PanelBar with two items in it .
Panel A is set to be expanded by default and none in case of Panel B

```
@(Html.Kendo().PanelBar().Name("panelbar")
.Items(items=>items.Add().Text("Panel A").Expanded("true").Content(@<div>content here</div>);
              items.Add().Text("Panel B").Content(@<div>content here</div>);

)
```

Result:
As Panelbar A was set to be expanded by default, it works fine.
But in case of PanelBar B, it is not expanding even after trying on client-side.
Any help will be appreciated,thanks.

Comment: Also this is  the jquery warning in Console :   Unknown DataSource transport type 'json'.
Verify that registration scripts for this type are included after Kendo UI on the page.

Comment: Any suggestions will be appreciated , thank you.